# Asymptotic behavior of a hypergeometric function

Tags: asymptotics, hypergeometric-functions

Can anybody see how to deduce an asymptotic formula for the hypergeometric function
$$ _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},x,x;x+\frac{1}{2},x+\frac{1}{2} \hskip2pt\bigg|\hskip2pt 1\right), \quad\mbox{ as } x\to\infty?$$

For the standard definition of the hypergeometric series, see [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.2).

**Remark**: I've tried to combine the numerous transformations and integral representations which $_3F_2$-functions fulfill. I've also tried to get inspired by existing works on asymptotic expansions of similar (but simpler) $_2F_1$-functions but never ended up with the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand\Ga\Gamma$Let $f(x)$ denote your hypergeometric expression. Then
$$f(x)\sim\sqrt{\pi x}$$
(as $x\to\infty$).

Indeed,
$$f(x)=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(1/2)_k}{k!}r_k(x)^2,$$
where $(a)_k:=a(a+1)\cdots(a+k-1)=\Ga(a+k)/\Ga(a)$ and
$$r_k(x):=\frac{(x)_k}{(x+1/2)_k}=\frac{\Ga(x+k)}{\Ga(x)}\Big/\frac{\Ga(x+1/2+k)}{\Ga(x+1/2)}
\sim\sqrt{\frac x{x+k}}$$
uniformly in $k\ge0$ (as $x\to\infty$).
So,
\begin{equation*}
    f(x)\sim x\,\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(1/2)_k}{k!} \frac1{x+k}
=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\, \Ga(x+1)}{\Ga(x+1/2)}
\sim\sqrt{\pi x} \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
(as $x\to\infty$).

---

**Details on the equality in \eqref{1}:**
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(1/2)_k}{k!} \frac1{x+k}
&   =\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(1/2)_k}{k!} \int_0^1 dt\,t^{x+k-1} \\ 
&   =\int_0^1 dt\,t^{x-1}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(1/2)_k}{k!} t^k  \\ 
&   =\int_0^1 dt\,t^{x-1}(1-t)^{-1/2}, 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
in view of the Maclaurin series for $(1-t)^{-1/2}$.
[Therefore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties),
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    x\,\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(1/2)_k}{k!} \frac1{x+k}
=x\,B(x,1/2)= x\,\frac{\Ga(1/2)\, \Ga(x)}{\Ga(x+1/2)}
=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\, \Ga(x+1)}{\Ga(x+1/2)}, 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
as claimed.

Answer (score 4):

Use the identity
$$_3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},x,x;x+\frac{1}{2},x+\frac{1}{2} \bigg|1\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\, \Gamma \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (x)}\,_3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,x+\frac{1}{2};1\right),$$
and the large-$x$ limits
$$_3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,x+\frac{1}{2};1\right)\rightarrow 1,$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\, \Gamma \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (x)}\rightarrow\sqrt{\pi x},$$
to conclude that
$$_3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},x,x;x+\frac{1}{2},x+\frac{1}{2} \bigg|1\right)\rightarrow \sqrt{\pi x}.$$

A numerical test shows that the $\sqrt{\pi x}$ asymptote (gold) is nearly indistinguishable from the exact function (blue) for $x$ larger than 4.

[image]

Comment: oh, I only saw your answer, Iosif, when I posted mine, apologies; the calculation is slightly different, so I'll just leave it here for the record.

Comment: Yes, Carlo, your approach is different. Can you give a reference on the displayed identity and details on $\to1$?

Comment: It is, for example, [Eq. 7.4.1.1] in Prudnikov, Brychkov, Marichev Vol. 3

Comment: Alas, I don't see this identity there. Here is what I see there instead: 
https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZxcHeVZ9MKRc5XWyyfYi6G0vETKQ4K73BQV

Comment: this is simply Mathematica output (somehow I no longer use the books I would have consulted in the past...)

Comment: Can you show how you used Mathematica to get this identity?

Comment: Limit[HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, x, x}, {1/2 + x, 1/2 + x}, 1 - eps], 
 eps -> 0]

Comment: Interesting ... I am wondering how (and when!) asking Mathematica to compute a limit (and what limit specifically?) results in such an identity. Is there any Mathematica documentation on this?

Comment: The reason I tried this limit is that $|z|=1$ is the radius of convergence of this hypergeometric function; I was hoping that Mathematica would be more knowledgeable within the radius of convergence than at its border.

Comment: Thefunctional identity for "$\rightarrow 1$" can be found here: http://functions.wolfram.com/07.27.17.0034.01

Comment: @JohannesTrost : Thank you for your comment. The problem with this, as with proofs of most results with Mathematica is that Wolfram gives almost no information about those proofs or the corresponding sources or methods.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Sorry, the reference should read Eq. 7.4.4.1 (not 7.4.1.1).

Comment: @Twi : Thank you for your comment. A problem with Prudnikov etal (as with Mathematica and in contrast with, say, Gradshteyn and Ryzhik), it is hard if at all possible to get information on how/where such a formula was derived.